# Jquery Hover to show image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Edit2:

Hi Guys,

i want to hover over "durchwahl" and make it popup a profile image on my mouse.
However, on the bottom of my page the images moves out of the visible area.
Is their a way i can fix it?
i am currently using jquery to popup an image @my mouse position:

index.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=encoding">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO 8859-1">
<script src="includes/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="includes/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show_confirm(user_id,status,freitext)
    {
        if (confirm("TeamViewer freigeben?"))
        {
            window.location.href="insert.php?user_id="+user_id+"&status="+status+"&freitext="+freitext+"&action=free_all_tv";
        }
    else
        {
            void('');
        };
    }

    function openWindow(Adresse)
    {
        MeinFenster = window.open(Adresse, "Zweitfenster", "width=400,height=110,left=100,top=200,resizeable=no");
        MeinFenster.focus();
    }

    function openpic(Pic)
    {   
        MeinFenster = window.open(Pic, Pic, "width=300,height=406,left=100,top=200,resizeable=no");
        MeinFenster.focus();
    }

    function change(href)
    {
        window.location.href=href;
    }
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/style.css">
<title>Anwesenheit</title>
</head>
```

style.css:

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
body {
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 75%;
text-decoration: none;
}



a{
text-decoration: none;     
color: #000000; 
   }

td,th{
border-radius:10px;
}

table{
border-spacing: 1px 5px;

}


#container
{

  display: inline-block; 
  width: 100%;          
  position: relative;   

}

#preview{
margin-left:-10%;
position:absolute;
border:1px solid #ccc;
background:#333;
padding:1px;
}


#Buttons {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 18px -5px #000000;  
border-radius:10px;
cursor:pointer; 
font-size:15px;   
width:auto;
margin-bottom:5px;
margin-right:2px;
margin-left:2px;
}



#Buttons:hover{
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform:scale(1.1);
  transform:scale(1.1); 
}


#BButton {
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 34px -5px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 34px -5px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px -5px #000000;
-moz-border-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
border-radius:10px;
display:inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:arial;
font-size:15px;
padding:2px 4px;
text-decoration:none;
padding: 5px;


}

#Remote {
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 34px -5px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 34px -5px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px -5px #000000;
-moz-border-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
border-radius:10px;
display:inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:arial;
font-size:15px;
padding:2px 4px;
text-decoration:none;
padding: 5px;
width: 185px;   
}

#Koffer {
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 34px -5px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 34px -5px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px -5px #000000;
-moz-border-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
border-radius:10px;
display:inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:arial;
font-size:15px;
padding:2px 4px;
text-decoration:none;
padding: 5px;
width: 135px;   
}

#Dongle {
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 34px -5px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 34px -5px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px -5px #000000;
-moz-border-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
border-radius:10px;
display:inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:arial;
font-size:15px;
padding:2px 4px;
text-decoration:none;
padding: 5px;
width: 145px;   
}

#Server {
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 34px -5px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 34px -5px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px -5px #000000;
-moz-border-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
border-radius:10px;
display:inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:arial;
font-size:15px;
padding:2px 4px;
text-decoration:none;
padding: 5px;
width: 115px;   
}

#Testone {
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 34px -5px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 34px -5px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px -5px #000000;
-moz-border-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
border-radius:10px;
display:inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:arial;
font-size:15px;
padding:2px 4px;
text-decoration:none;
padding: 5px;
width: 145px;   
}

#Testtwo {
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 34px -5px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 34px -5px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px -5px #000000;
-moz-border-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
border-radius:10px;
display:inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:arial;
font-size:15px;
padding:2px 4px;
text-decoration:none;
padding: 5px;
width: 110px;   
}

#bottom {
border-spacing: 10px 5px;
}
```

functions.php:

```
$value = $value . "<a  href='images/".getPictureName($nutzer['vorname'],$nutzer['nachname']).".jpg' class='preview'> <img   class='img' src='images/phone.jpg' border='0' width='12' height='12'>".$nutzer['durchwahl'];
```

Comment: where is your jquery code?

Comment: Also, the link has a class but the CSS is using an ID.

Comment: **`:)`**  . For CsS ,use class always ,and for jQuery use iD!

Comment: For Jquery use class if you need to select anything of that class...which is the case here.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").hover(function(){
          $('img').css({'display':'block'});
        },function(){
         $('img').css({'display':'none'});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Hover the mouse pointer over this paragraph.</p>
<img src='a.png' style='display:none'>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this . On hover

img is displaying .

Comment: on hover Why Dont u use ->           `$('img').css({'display':'block'});` ?